# Text formatting doesn't appear in emails that have been formatted using TinyMCE and sent using SwiftMailer

Tags: php, tinymce, swiftmailer, email-client

I use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) in my PHP scripts to send emails and I use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) as a text editor to write and format the message body. The problem is that when I send the message it appears without any formatting in all email clients (gmail, yahoo and hotmail), and even links doesn't appear as links, they appear as normal text but in blue. so what is the problem?

Here is the code I use to send emails:

```
<?php

require_once 'path/to/SwiftMailer/lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
# Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
# Create the message
$msg = Swift_Message::newInstance();
# Give the message a subject
$msg->setSubject($_POST['subject']);
# Set the From address with an associative array
$msg->setFrom(array($_POST['sender_email'] => $_POST['sender_name']));
# Give it a body
$msg->setBody($_POST['message'], 'text/html');

$failedRecipients = array();
$numSent = 0;
$to = array(
    'recipient_1@gmail.com',
    'recipient_2@yahoo.com' => 'Recipient 2',
    'recipient_3@hotmail.com',
    'recipient_4@gmail.com' => 'Recipient 4',
    'recipient_5@yahoo.com'
);

foreach ($to as $address => $name) {
    if (is_int($address)) {
        $msg->setTo($name);
    } else {
        $msg->setTo(array($address => $name));
    }

    $numSent += $mailer->send($msg, $failedRecipients);
}

echo $numSent > 0 ? 'SUCCESS' : 'FAILURE';

?>
```

note that `$_POST['message']` holds body of the message that I have written and formatted using TinyMCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried many things till I figure it out, the problem was that special characters in the formatted message body was being escaped (a back slash was being added in the front of each special character) I don't know why, and I don't know which of them (TinyMCE or SwiftMailer) that did this. So all I needed to do is to strip slashes out of the message body before sending the message throught SwiftMailer. I have just needed to change this line:

```
$msg->setBody($_POST['message'], 'text/html');
```

to be:

```
$msg->setBody(stripslashes($_POST['message']), 'text/html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not used Swiftmailer before but as a starting point it looks like it's stripping (not escaping) the HTML tags out of the content before sending. Are you able to post your code as it may be something you're doing there or something swift mailer itself is doing.

A quick look on swiftmailer and it looks like it supports html messages so it may also be the case that you're not using the correct MIME type.

Comment: I've posted the code that I use to send my messages, and SwiftMailer doesn't strip the HTML tags before sending.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your html email does not contain the stylesheet that is available in your tinymce editor. Make sure the same stylesheet gets apllied to your email content.